# Multiple drag and drop in JQuery: event after dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I am actually trying to make a .php page where I am going to have 3 draggable elements which have to be dragged to 3 droppable elements -each draggable to a droppable, and they are unique, so one each droppable will only accept a certain draggable.

The thing is that I need to control that all of the elements have been dragged to the right spot, in which case I should redirect the user for example to success.php, otherwise, if some of the elements were dragged to the wrong droppable, the user have to go to for example failure.php.

Is there anyway for example to save a certain value in a $_SESSION in PHP in order to know that all the draggables have been dropped in the right place?

This is the code for the drag&drop:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggableLeiden").draggable();
    $("#draggableTheHague").draggable();
    $("#draggableRotterdam").draggable();

    $("#droppableLeiden").droppable({
        accept: '.imgLeiden',
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');

        }
    });
    $("#droppableTheHague").droppable({
        accept: '.imgTheHague',
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');

        }
    });
    $("#droppableRotterdam").droppable({
        accept: '.imgRotterdam',
        drop: function() 
        {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            //var activeClass = $(this).droppable('option', 'activeClass','ui-state-highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to do this for example getting the active class of the droppable elements to see if it matches 'ui-state-highlight', but actually, that  tag is gonna be executed everytime the page reloads, so if I try to insert any code into the
drop: function()
it will always execute.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I am working on a solution. I'll post later when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [revert](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) option instead. When a draggable element is dropped on anything but the accepted droppable element then it will slide back to its original spot. Does this work for you?

Comment: Well not exactly, because the user is not supposed to use trial&error, so the best would be to send the user to another page depending on the action he took.

But thanks a lot anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance looking for `ui.draggable` it holds the element that was dropped?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

```
$('#target').droppable({
    drop : function(event,ui){
            if($(ui.draggable).attr('id') == "correcttarget")
            {
                    window.location = "yay.php";
            }
            else
            {
                    window.location = "awwww.php";
            }
    }
})
```

Comment: yeah well that might work! but how to make it to gone to a certain webpage when THE THREE draggables have been dropped to their right droppables?

Comment: @noloman Keep a global variable, either an array of conditions or a simple counter that checks if there are 3 successes, add this in the `correcttarget` branch `counter++;if(counter==3){ /* action here */}`